how to use typescript Compiler API to get all exported functions that return a JSX.Element?
I would like to have a function that receives a string with some TSX source code and returns a list with the exported functions that have the  JSX.Element as a return type inferred.
I started by returning a list of the exported functions and their return types to see what I get, and I noticed I get the return type 'any' for functions that return a JSX.Element.
Why is Typescript not able to return the correct return type in this case?
Here is some code that can be run in node using npx tsx index.ts:
import ts from 'typescript'

interface ExportedJSXInfo {
    name: string
    returnType?: string
}

export function readComponentSource(sourceCode: string): ExportedJSXInfo[] {
    const exportedJSXInfos: ExportedJSXInfo[] = []

    const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile('tempFile.tsx', sourceCode, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, true, ts.ScriptKind.TSX)

    const options: ts.CompilerOptions = {
        jsx: ts.JsxEmit.React,
        allowJs: true,
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
        module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    }
    const host: ts.CompilerHost = {
        getSourceFile: fileName => (fileName === 'tempFile.tsx' ? sourceFile : undefined),
        writeFile: () => {},
        getDefaultLibFileName: () => 'lib.d.ts',
        useCaseSensitiveFileNames: () => true,
        getCanonicalFileName: fileName => fileName,
        getCurrentDirectory: () => '',
        getNewLine: () => '\n',
        fileExists: fileName => fileName === 'tempFile.tsx',
        readFile: fileName => (fileName === 'tempFile.tsx' ? sourceCode : ''),
        directoryExists: () => true,
        getDirectories: () => [],
    }
    const program = ts.createProgram(['tempFile.tsx'], options, host)
    const checker = program.getTypeChecker()

    function getReturnType(node: ts.Node): string | undefined {
        if (
            ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node) ||
            ts.isFunctionExpression(node) ||
            ts.isArrowFunction(node) ||
            ts.isMethodDeclaration(node)
        ) {
            const type = checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(node)?.getReturnType()
            if (type) {
                return checker.typeToString(type)
            }
        }
        return undefined
    }

    function visit(node: ts.Node) {
        if (ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node) && node.modifiers?.some(modifier => modifier.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword)) {
            const returnType = node.type ? node.type.getText() : getReturnType(node)
            exportedJSXInfos.push({
                name: node.name?.text as string,
                returnType,
            })
        }

        if (ts.isVariableStatement(node) && node.modifiers?.some(modifier => modifier.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword)) {
            node.declarationList.declarations.forEach(declaration => {
                if (ts.isVariableDeclaration(declaration)) {
                    const variableType = declaration.type ? declaration.type.getText() : getReturnType(declaration)
                    if (variableType) {
                        exportedJSXInfos.push({
                            name: (declaration.name as ts.Identifier).text,
                            returnType: variableType,
                        })
                    } else if (declaration.initializer) {
                        if (
                            ts.isArrowFunction(declaration.initializer) ||
                            ts.isFunctionExpression(declaration.initializer)
                        ) {
                            const functionType = declaration.initializer.type
                                ? declaration.initializer.type.getText()
                                : getReturnType(declaration.initializer)
                            exportedJSXInfos.push({
                                name: (declaration.name as ts.Identifier).text,
                                returnType: functionType,
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        ts.forEachChild(node, visit)
    }

    visit(sourceFile)
    return exportedJSXInfos
}

// Example usage:
const sourceCode = `

   export function Test()  {
    return "123"
  }
  
   export function MyComponent()  {
    return <div>Hello, world!</div>;
  }

   export const MyOtherComponent = () => <div>Hello again!</div>;

   const NotAComponent = 42;
`

const exportedJSXInfos = readComponentSource(sourceCode)
console.log(exportedJSXInfos)


Running this script will output:
[
  { name: 'Test', returnType: 'string' },
  { name: 'MyComponent', returnType: 'any' },
  { name: 'MyOtherComponent', returnType: 'any' }
]


